# out-of-sample variance using rolling window

Tags: r, portfolio, variance, bootstrap

I am currently working on the comparison of the constructed portfolios using out-of-sample variance criteria. I am going to use rolling window procedure for the comparison. First, I choose a window over which to perform estimation. Length of estimation window let say `t` is smaller than `N`, where `N` is the total number of returns. I use estimation window of `t=60` data points which correspond to 5 years for monthly data. Second, using the return data over the estimation window, `t`, I compute various portfolios. I repeat this rolling window procedure for the next month and dropping the data for the earliest month. I continue this until the end of the dataset is reached. At the end of the this process, I will have generated `T-t` portfolio weight vectors for each strategy. Does anyone know which package I can use for rolling window algorithm in R or matlab? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

R package [TTR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/index.html) has rolling window algorithms and understands day counting etc. It stands on the shoulders of xts (which extends zoo) and quantmod

Comment: Thank you very much. I think rollSFM takes single-factor model parameters over a n-period moving window such as                                         'rollSFM(Ra, Rb, n = 60)' in the TTR package. I will not use factor model or need market returns. I only have asset returns. I will compute covariance matrix to get the asset weights.